# Ngrok client is started but the web also show the Tunnelx.x:8080 not found

Tags: tunnel, ngrok

[image: Error code]

[image: Tunnel status]

The web server can run normally but just can't find the tunnel in the server.

`Tunnel x.x:8080 not found`

What should I do to start the tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

can check whether your apache or whatever, webserver you are using, is running. If not, start it that should solve the problem.